# Is there a textbook for learning physics and multivariable calculus at the same time?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, calculus

I am a student who took single variable calculus and algebra physics.

I want to learn either mechanics or thermodynamics or electromagnetism with multivariable calculus, matrices, lagrange multipliers.

What are some of the best resources for accomplishing this?

Comment: may I humbly suggest an alternate approach (based on my own missteps) : I think it is just more fruitful to pick up a *physics* book and start reading, and, have a mathematical methods book handy, as a reference. I can suggest Mary L. Boas's book. It is dated, but covers the fundamentals well. In general, I personally feel that it is more fruitful to focus on the *physics*, and pick up the *math* on the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Introduction to Electrodynamics by Grittiths would be perfect for you! It has a chapter that is solely dedicated to multivariable calculus, which the rest of the book then uses for the majority of the problems. It also has a more "chill" tone which makes it easier to read, if you're just starting to learn physics.